# Do the brachas of Al Haeitz and Al Hagafen generally have the same halachos as Al Hamichya

Tags: halacha, blessing, birkat-meeyn-shalosh

For example, should one sit for them like they do for AL Hamichya. and etc ...

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Can you be more specific with what you mean to ask about by stating exactly what the etc is? Also what prompted you to think they should be different? These details would improve the quality of your question. Welcome to MiYodeya.

Comment: There may be a difference between their status as *doiraysa* v. *drabanan*, according to some opinions. [This isn't a direct answer, because this isn't a difference in halacha. It can have some strong ramifications, however]

Answer (score 3):

This is a Machloket Haposkim.

See Shulchan Aruch OC 183.10

> יש אומרים שגם ברכת מעין שלש צריך לאמרה מיושב
>
> There are some who say that even Beracha Meen Shalosh have to be said when sitting.

Mishna Berura sk 35:

> שגם ברכת מעין שלש - עיין בביאור הגר"א שתלה דין זה במה שמבואר לקמן בסימן קפ"ד ס"ג והרמב"ם שהוא בעל דעה זו אזיל לשיטתו שם ולפ"ז בחמשת מיני דגן עכ"פ לכ"ע צריך להיות דוקא ברכה אחרונה שלהם בישיבה

The Gaon Mivilna says that this depends from the rule regarding to return to the place where we ate treated in 184.3

184.3

> יש אומרים שכל שבעת המינים טעונים ברכה לאחריהם במקומם ויש אומרים דחמשת מיני דגן דוקא

There are two opinions, the first is that for all 7 species we have to return to the place where we ate (Rambam, Mordechai), and the second (Rosh) is that for the 5 species of cereal only we have to return.

So, the same disagreement is for the need to sit regarding Al Haets and Al Haggefen, but for Al Hamichia we need to sit and Rambam and Rosh unanimous. But Tosfot holds that this rule is only for Birkat Hamazon. (See Kaf Hachayim sk 50)